# Why is my Drawing panel, sometimes painting and other time not, on window resize?

Tags: java, swing, drawing, paintcomponent

I have this simple application in which a command like `RECT 10 20 100 150` draws a rectangle with specified arguments on a DrawPanel(extends `JPanel`).

Also, after drawing the primitive, it adds it to `List<String> cmdList;`, so that in
`paintComponent(Graphics g)` of DrawPanel I iterate through the list, process each command, and draw each of them.

**The problem** I am facing is that after drawing few shapes, and resizing (or maximizing) the  panel becomes empty. And on resizing again several times, all the shpaes get drawn correctly.

This is the screenshot after drawing few primitives.
[image]

After stretching window slightly to left, the primitives are gone.
[image]

The code for **DrawPanel**

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    
    private List<String> cmdList;
    public final Map<String,Shape> shapes;
    
    public DrawPanel()
    {
        shapes = new HashMap<String,Shape>();
        shapes.put("CIRC", new Circ());
        shapes.put("circ", new Circ());
        shapes.put("RECT", new Rect());
        shapes.put("rect", new Rect());
        shapes.put("LINE", new Line());
        //... and so on
    
        cmdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    public void addCmd(String s)
    {
        cmdList.add(s);
    }
    public void removeCmd()
    {
        cmdList.remove(cmdList.size());
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        
        for (int i = 0;  i < cmdList.size(); ++i){
            StringTokenizer cmdToken = new StringTokenizer(cmdList.get(i));
            
            String cmdShape = cmdToken.nextToken(); 
            int []args = new int[cmdToken.countTokens()];
            
            for(int i1 = 0; cmdToken.hasMoreTokens(); i1++){
                args[i1] = Integer.valueOf(cmdToken.nextToken());
            }
            
            shapes.get(cmdShape).draw(this, args);
        }
    }
    
    public void getAndDraw(String cmdShape, int[] args)
    {
        shapes.get(cmdShape).draw(this, args);
    }
    public void rect(int x1, int y1, int width, int height)
    {
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawRect(x1, y1, width, height);
    }
    public void circ(int cx, int cy, int radius)
    {
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.drawOval(cx - radius, cy - radius, radius*2, radius*2);
    }
}
```

The partial code for **Shape** (Interface)

```
public interface Shape {
    void draw(DrawPanel dp, int[] data);
}

class Rect implements Shape {
    public void draw(DrawPanel dp, int[] data) {
        dp.rect(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
    }
}
```

Lines used in **MainFrame** (extends `JFrame`) to draw after each command is entered.

```
drawPanel.getAndDraw(cmdShape, args);
drawPanel.addCmd(cmd);
```

Why is Drawing panel, sometimes painting and other time not, on window resize?
How can I get stable output?

Note : If I have missed anything, please ask.

Comment: COuld you provide SSCCE?

Comment: @StanislavL: Is SSCCE a single file, containing all the relevant code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your using getGraphics() when you should be using the Graphics object passed as an argument to paintComponent.

Oh, and btw, setBackground(Color.BLACK) should be in the constructor, not in the paintComponent method.

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem :) But one thing, now every function has one additional argument (`Graphics g`), can (or should) I avoid it?

Comment: No, I thinks it's the best way to do that